# Error Undefined error:addition in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating some code using laravel in controller and i want send array from controller to blade file i face problem 1/1) ErrorException

> Undefined variable: addition It runs but now face this error

```
$get_details=DB::select('SELECT deliver_date,GROUP_CONCAT(orders_qty) as orders_qty FROM `orders` WHERE order_status=? and deliver_date between ? AND ? GROUP BY deliver_date',[6,'2019-02-01','2020-02-05']);

         foreach($get_details as $date_wise_details)
        {
            $array=explode(',',$date_wise_details->orders_qty);
            $addition[]=array_sum($array);
        }
 return view('dashboard',['get_data'=>$get_details])->with('addition',$addition);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `addition` array to resolve this issue

```
      $addition = []; // define your array here
       foreach($get_details as $date_wise_details)
        {
            $array=explode(',',$date_wise_details->orders_qty);
            $addition[]=array_sum($array);
        }
```

Comment: check the output of `dd($array)` in your foreach loop you must b getting blank data